# Opera browser menu border transparency broken in LXDE on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, 22.04, lxde, opera, transparency

Opera web browser 106.0.4998.19 in LXDE 11 on Ubuntu 22.04 (freshly updated) has some issues with the main and all the context menu border transparency. Instead of the transparent background, there is a solid white border and a black shadow. I got the embedded video in my Intel Core i7-8700. This appearance has been tested with the hardware acceleration feature switched on and off - no difference.

See the Opera browser issues' in LXDE screenshots below:
[image: Main menu border transparency broken]
[image: Context menu border transparency broken]

All these menus look well with proper border transparency when I switch to Gnome 42.9 on the same PC. So I guess there may be some Gnome libs that could be loaded somehow when working in LXDE 11, but I don't know how to do this, and Google has told me nothing certain.

What could be done to get the proper Opera menu border transparency in LXDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've installed **picom** with the command:

```
sudo apt install picom
```

and added it to autostart in the LXSession settings to be run with the command:

```
picom --daemon
```

and after the system restart it hepled all the menus to get the proper transparency.